# Beamer and unicode-math together make log-like operators disappear

Tags: beamer, math-operators, unicode-math

Using `beamer` and `unicode-math` together leads to the disappearance of all log-like operators (`\log`, `\mod`, `\sin`, etc.), as shown by the following minimal file. Interestingly, compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex leads to a different whitespace “occupied” by the missing `\log`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  log$|log|\log|\mathrm{log}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This does not happens in the `article` class or without the `unicode-math` package. Is there a work-around for this bug ?

Comment: For what it’s worth, adding `\setoperatorfont\mathrm` in the preamble doesn’t change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override the default math font choice:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  log$|log|\log|\mathrm{log}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However this might not be what you want; presently there's no sans serif Unicode math font.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But if it is a sans-serif font problem, why do my other attempts to move to a math serif font (via `\setoperatorfont\mathrm` or `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`) fail ?